# Calculating SCS curve numbers using DSM instead of DTM

Tags: dem, hydrology

Are the curve numbers (calculated by SCS Curve number method) through DSM (Digital Surface Model) valid? Most of the SCS curve number studies focus on calculating curve numbers through a DTM (Digital Terrain Model).

As the DSM has heights of man made (buildings, roads, siphon structures etc.) and natural features (rocks, trees etc.) is it better to model bridges on it as well?